# With PM2 cluster mode, how to keep state consistency between nodejs instances

Tags: node.js, pm2, cluster-mode

I made my nodejs app based on the controller/service/model architecture. All my services are classes with static methods called by controllers or others services.

The services class can also have static properties that are used to "cache" some data from DB that won't change in a while, so I query the DB only once at startup then I only read the class static property when I need it instead to query the DB, so I got huge gain in performance.

The best example is for the list of feature permissions that has been set once and that almost never change, but that it is read by almost ALL api call:

permission.service.js

```
const { PermissionModel } = require("../models/permission.model");

class PermissionService {
    static cachedPerms = []

    static updateCache = async => {
        PermissionService.cachedPerms = await PermissionModel.getPerms()
    }

    static createPermission = async perm => { 
        await PermissionModel.createPerm(perm)
        await PermissionService.updateCache()
    }

    static updatePermission = async perm{ 
        await PermissionModel.updatePerm(perm)
        await PermissionService.updateCache()
    }
}

// cache update is made at first eval of the file when app starts
PermissionService.updateCache()

module.exports = PermissionService
```

This works very well on my dev environment with only one instance of my nodejs app running, but what if I use the cluster mode in production environment with multiple instances of my app?

When the static property of my service's class is updated on one instance, how I make all the others instances run their own `PermissionService.updateCache()` so they got all the updated data?